# Connecting homomorphism in generalized cohomology theory

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, oa.operator-algebras, index-theory

I have some compact manifold with boundary $(M,\partial M)$, and there is a long exact sequence

$$\cdots\to KO^{-1}(\partial M)\xrightarrow{\partial} KO^{0}(M,\partial M)\to KO^0(M)\to KO^0(\partial M) $$

I want to understand the connecting homomorphism. My question is:

> > In general, are there any geometric descriptions of the "cycles" in $KO$ theory and the connecting homomorphism?

Comment: Sort of. I suggest you look in *Index theory for skew-adjoint Fredholm operators* by Atiyah and Singer and *Clifford modules* by Atiyah, Bott and Shapiro for a description in terms of modules over a Clifford algebra.

Comment: The negative K groups are the easier part: $K^{-1}(\partial M)$ is just $K^0(\Sigma \partial M)$. The connecting homomorphism is just pulling back the bundle using the standard, geometric map $M/\partial M \rightarrow \Sigma \partial M$. (Build this by viewing $M/\partial M$ as collapsing a cone on $\partial M$ and just include into the `double cone' which is the suspension.)